Uses of the interactive LaTeX session?
If I run latex (or pdflatex) in the command line, I get a prompt:
$ latex                                                                     
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**

and I can type there.
Sometimes I get this type of things after running into a document error too.
This looks like some sort of "interactive" session of LaTeX.
What is the purpose of this interactive input? issue commands? type a document?
It seems to be a possible way to interact with the Latex production of the document, perhaps (in theory) recover from errors.
Is that correct?
Where can I find documentation on how to use an interactive session of LaTeX?
If so, that also seems to be a way to control LaTeX from another program, i.e. without an intermediate document (.tex) file.
Are there other ways to control a latex session interactively?

There are no other ways to an interactive LaTeX session. During error recovery you can hit i to specify tokens that should be input (in order to solve the error, back when it took much time to compile a TeX document this was means to reduce overall time, since you could continue your run and fix the issue in your editor later). Note that the start of this interactive run differs from further prompts (during the first prompt you get **, later only *) on the first prompt if you start typing TeX expects you to insert a file name (entering \relax is a safe way to bypass that), [...]

[...] afterwards you can simply input your document as you're used to, just not in an editor but directly in the prompt.

Did you try it out? You can indeed type in a document, line by line, and when you type \end{document} the prompt is closed and a pdf is produced. You can also recover from errors, if you type in a misspelled command then you can correct it.

The behaviour is documented in the TeXbook. If you're lucky enough to have access to a printed version just consult it. Otherwise the sources are free (and for the most part readable), just note that you're not allowed to typeset these sources into a document (and any PDF version you find on the internet is most likely a copyright infringement, there are no legal PDFs, afaik)

There are better ways to control LaTeX from another program though, depending on what you mean with 'control', there are for example templating engines like Scriban or Jinja, or DOM-like libraries such as PyLaTeX. They allow you to compose a document on the fly, then write it into a .tex file which is compiled normally, but this gives a lot of programmatic flexibility.

@Skillmon, I didn't understand the difference between ** and *. I think that explains my frustration with the interactive mode. I can accept your comment as an answer.

TeX has several prompts asking for input on the commandline,
** is asking for a file name, and only appears at the start of a run, for example  if you respond with small2e :
$ pdflatex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**small2e
entering extended mode
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/small2e.tex
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-08-30>
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./small2e.aux) (/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/omscmr.fd)
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}{/usr/l
ocal/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-ts1.enc}]
(./small2e.aux) )</usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfont
s/cm/cmbx10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts
/cm/cmbx12.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/
cm/cmr10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm
/cmsy10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/
cmti10.pfb></usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/cm-super/sfrm
1000.pfb>
Output written on small2e.pdf (1 page, 67407 bytes).
Transcript written on small2e.log.

This is equivalent to the more normal use
pdflatex small2e

where you give a filename on the commandline.
Just as on the commandline if the first tokens are not letters, then they are taken as TeX commands rather than a filename, and if further input is needed a * prompt (with just one *) is issued.
This shows a terminal session in which the entire document is typed interactively to the * prompt. As no file was given the \jobname defaults to  texput and texput.pdf is created.
$ pdflatex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**\relax
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-08-30>

*\documentclass{article}

*\begin{document}x\end{document}
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2024/02/08 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
No file texput.aux.

[1{/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}]
(./texput.aux)</usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/c
m/cmr10.pfb>
Output written on texput.pdf (1 page, 9522 bytes).
Transcript written on texput.log.

After an error TeX issues a ? prompt. to which you could type x to stop or as here, type i to insert tokens (here avoiding further errors by defining \bbb)
$ pdflatex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
**\aaaa\bbbb
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e <2024-06-01> patch level 2
L3 programming layer <2024-08-30>
! Undefined control sequence.
<*> \aaaa
         \bbbb
? i\def\bbbb{\stop}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on texput.log.

There are other prompts for example if you try to input a missing file you get
$ pdflatex bad
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.26 (TeX Live 2024) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
! I can't find file `bad'.
<*> bad
       
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name: 

This can be a hard prompt to escape from in some systems, where it is not always eay to enter Ctrl-D  LaTeX supplies files such as x.tex which allows you to type x to this prompt which inputs a file that stops the job:
! I can't find file `bad'.
l.4 \input{bad}
               
(Press Enter to retry, or Control-D to exit)
Please type another input file name: x
(/usr/local/texlive/2024/texmf-dist/tex/latex/tools/x.tex



thanks, that is a great explanation. can something be done with the document other than \end{document}? for example can it be “flushed”? or restarted? can another document be rendered after that?

@alfC no the facilities are exactly the same as the facilities available from a file, it's just using stdin rather than a file but is otherwise identical.

got it. so, the ** prompt is never to come back.

couldn't you initiate another job before \end{document} if running with shell escape?

well you could ,yes "exactly the same facilities as a file" although it's likely to get terribly messed up as they would be using the same stdin and stdout @cfr
